# Android android.lintOptions.abortOnError for release builds only

Tags: android, android-lint

I'd like to set strict lint checking on my CI and it would be nice if I could set the `abortOnError` bit for lint only when I run a release build. I've tried:

```
compileLint.doFirst {
    android.applicationVariants.each { variant ->
        android.lintOptions.abortOnError variant.name.endsWith('Release')
        println("variant.name? ${project.name}/${variant.name} abortOnError? ${android.lintOptions.abortOnError}")
    }
}
```

I also did the same thing with `preBuild`. When I run `:app:lintProdRelease` I do see that my task ran and the print says

```
app/prodRelease abortOnError true
app/prodDebug abortOnError false
app/mockDebug abortOnError false
```

But every time I run `:app:lintProdRelease` I see the lint error but the build succeeds. How can I configure lint check based on the build type?